# Paypal Recurring Payment - Charge immediately?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I am using the Paypal API and I want to create a recurring payment, the first amount should be charged immediately. I need to know if it was successfully to unlock the content for the user. How in the world can I achieve that?

```
$fields = array(




    'USER' => urlencode('email'),

    'PWD' => urlencode('pass'),

    'SIGNATURE' => urlencode('signature'),

    'METHOD' => urlencode('GetExpressCheckoutDetails'),

    'VERSION' => urlencode('86'),

    'TOKEN' => urlencode($_GET['token'])




);


//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');




$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);




// Get PAYERID of 1. query

$payerid = parseNVP($server_output);

$payerid = $payerid['PAYERID'];





$fields2 = array(




    'USER' => urlencode('Email'),

    'PWD' => urlencode('Pass'),

    'SIGNATURE' => urlencode('Signature'),

    'METHOD' => urlencode('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile'),

    'VERSION' => urlencode('86'),

    'TOKEN' => urlencode($_GET['token']),

    'PAYERID' => urlencode($payerid),

'PROFILESTARTDATE' => urlencode(date('Y-m-d').'T'.date('H:i:s', strtotime('-5 minutes')).'Z'),

'DESC' => urlencode('FitnessMembership'),

'BILLINGPERIOD' => urlencode('Day'),

'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => urlencode('1'),

'AMT' => urlencode($price),

'CURRENCYCODE' => urlencode('USD'),

'COUNTRYCODE' => urlencode('US'),

'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => urlencode('3')





);
```

Paypal Result:

```
 [2016-04-12 12:50 America/New_York] Verified IPN:cmd=_notify-validate&
payment_cycle=Daily&
txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_created&
last_name=Mustermann&
next_payment_date=03%3A00%3A00+Apr+12%2C+2016+PDT&
residence_country=US&
initial_payment_amount=0.00&
currency_code=USD&
time_created=09%3A49%3A25+Apr+12%2C+2016+PDT&
verify_sign=AJjtUEC2-zvkp.2Yz8a-.FGmZ2b3AoUov3DJ70yddjCmc1KidQVDeZHd&
period_type=+Regular&
payer_status=verified&
test_ipn=1&
tax=0.00&
payer_email=gut%40gut.de&
first_name=Hendrik&
receiver_email=hendrik.tewes-facilitator%40live.de&
payer_id=6AJ2HHWAPZSF6&
product_type=1&shipping=0.00&
amount_per_cycle=119.00&
profile_status=Active&
charset=windows-1252&
notify_version=3.8&
amount=119.00&
outstanding_balance=0.00&
recurring_payment_id=I-8P0534LSX2A3&
product_name=FitnessMembership&
ipn_track_id=59fede576b95c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can charge an initial amount when creating a Recurring Payment Profile for Express Checkout. 
Here is [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) from the PayPal Developer Site
In the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API call, you will need to use the variable `INITAMT`

Here is more information from the PayPal Developer Site:

> **INITAMT**
>
> (Optional) Initial non-recurring payment amount due immediately upon
>   profile creation. Use an initial amount for enrolment or set-up fees.
>
> **Note**: All amounts included in the request must have the same currency.
>
> Character length and limitations:
>
> Value is typically a positive number which cannot exceed 10,000.00 USD
>   or the per transaction limit for the currency. It includes no currency
>   symbol. Most currencies require two decimal places; the decimal
>   separator must be a period (.), and the optional thousands separator
>   must be a comma (,). Some currencies do not allow decimals. See the
>   currency codes page for details.